# There was a problem reaching this app - Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am very new to Microsoft Teams App. I tried the custom "hello world" app. C# application is set up correctly and I can see the output in the browser.

Validation of an app is successful in App Studio. Now, I uploaded custom apps to MS Teams but it gives error as mention in the title. I added a new policy in SetUp policy in the admin. center and added myself in Managed Users. Still, I am not able to see hello world message when my app is added as Tab in MS Teams portal. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

App Studio is a Teams app that simplifies the creation and registration of an app. Since your app is working perfectly in the browser, the next step will be to update the app package in App Studio. Hope you added the manifest file in the App studio Manifest Editor.

Please refer the URL - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio